What should the values of R1 and R2 be in this discrete component CMOS NAND gate, if I even need them?
I've done some experimenting in simulations with CMOS, and so far, I've settled on this standard design, which includes two resistors that both limit shoot through and prevent ringing and current spikes on the gate of the FETs, two clamping diodes to protect from over- and under-voltage on the gate, and a small decoupling capacitor.
However, I'm not sure what I should have R1 and R2 set to, or if I even need them. The Rds(on) of the BS250P is, according to the datasheet, typically 3.5 Ohms, and the BS170 is typically 1.2 Ohms, so while it's not a short circuit, it doesn't feel like a lot of current limiting is being done when switching. I definitely think 100 Ohms is too high, as it takes ~100ns for Q to reach Vss after the inputs change, which is much higher than the switching speeds of either FET. When I lower the value to 10 Ohms, it halves that time, but that suggests to me that it's a matter of diminishing returns between speed and increased power consumption and possible damage to the FETs.
What would be a good value for R1 and R2 in this case?
NAND

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

What is your point in studying this circuit? Components have different costs in different implementations; in particular, resistors are costly in monolithic integrated circuits.
